# Validating file extension in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have written a custom validation to check filename extensions, using carrierwave (I know this wouldn’t stop a file being faked) but for know it will suffice.

However I don’t think I have quite got it though, or at least I think this could be optimized

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
validate :file_format, :if => 'media?'
  def file_format
    filename = self.media.filename
      if filename !~ /.(png|PNG|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|mp4|MP4|docx|DOCX|pdf|PDF)/
       errors[:document] << "File format not supported"
      end
  end
end
```

Could the regular expression take into account for case insensitive (using `i` I believe)?

When I upload a file now the request just hangs, though when I reload the page the file is there. I think there is an issue with my validation method.

Comment: Not sure, but I believe the 'media?' value to if should be a symbol!! Maybe not related, though.

Comment: well I think its ok, works on other validations that i have set using 'media?' its from the docs..besides have tried symbol and same behaviour

Comment: You need to escape the period. Otherwise it matches any character. I would use, `! filename.match(/\.(png|jpg|jpeg|mp4|docx|pdf)$/i)`

Comment: It's more idiomatic to use symbols. I know it has nothing to do with your issue, but just pointing it out.

Comment: @lurker so how would i say if filename doesnt match?

Comment: See the `!` in front of my expression. :)

Comment: haha, sorry, missed that for some reason :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can handle validating filename extensions right from your CarrierWave `Uploader` class.

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def extension_white_list
    %w( jpg jpeg png pdf mp4 docx doc )
  end
end
```

If you're determined to do this validation from within the containing model, why even use a regex?

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :file_format, if: :media?

  def file_format
    unless valid_extension? self.media.filename
      errors[:document] << "Invalid file format."
    end
  end

  def valid_extension?(filename)
    ext = File.extname(filename)
    %w( jpg jpeg png pdf mp4 docx doc ).include? ext.downcase
  end
end
```

That is much simpler and reads easier, especially since you aren't using any other regex features.

Comment: thanks, well i do have `extension_white_list` in my uploader class.. how could i show error messages then just using that?

Comment: @Richlewis CarrierWave will automatically mark your model as invalid if it doesn't match the `extension_white_list`.  `model.document = File.new("invalid.extension"); model.valid? #=> false`

Comment: @Richlewis The same way you are validating your model using `validates :file_format` now. In other words, you can just check the return value of `model.save` to see if the validation has passed. The error message will be applied to the CarrierWave attribute, just like normal validations.

Comment: ok thanks for the info...One more thing sorry.. I have tried to upload a.html file, the upload does not go ahead, but there is no error message shown...any ideas?

Comment: @Richlewis You can get the error from the `errors` object. You should try something like `<%= @model.errors.full_messages.join("<br/>") %>` from within your view. Check out [the rails validation guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views) for more in-depth coverage of validations.

Comment: A small consideration:
`%w(.jpg .jpeg .png .pdf .docx .doc).include? ext.downcase`
It is necessary `.` before extensions

Answer (score 1):

Sure, `//i` is case-insensitive regex.

I'd also put a \Z at the end of your regex, otherwise you're matching files with eg "PNG" anywhere in them, not just at the end.

Also, you need to escape the `.`, or it means "any character", not a period.

```
/\.(png|PNG|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|mp4|MP4|docx|DOCX|pdf|PDF)\Z/
```

Also, are you sure you want to validate based on filename, and not on MIME type, or both?

I think your problem with hanging is probably not due to your validation, but due to other aspects of the carrierwave integration. But there's an easy way to find out, turn off the validation and see if the hanging problem is still there.

Comment: thanks, i have just found out why the page is hanging..if a document saves it is supposed to redirect, but as im using the gem 'remotipart' its causing all uploads to process as js, so im getting no redirects at the moment..bit stumped now

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while for this question, so here is a working example for Rails v4 to create a custom validator (`app/validators/file_validator.rb`):

```
class FileValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value
      if value.respond_to? :path
        unless options[:ext].include? File.extname(value.original_filename).delete('.').to_sym
          record.errors[attribute] << " is not a valid file (#{options[:ext].join(',')})"
        end
      else
        record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || 'is not a file')
      end
    end
  end

end
```

example of usage (user model):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :avatar_file

  # other validators ...
  
  # Avatar validation
  validates :avatar_file, file: {ext: [:jpg, :png]}

  # logic...

end
```

This simple validator check for image extensions (jpg, png).